# How to insert row and section into UICollectionView at same time?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In `UITableViewController` I can insert row and section at the same time with this implementations:

```
    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        if controller == frc {

            switch(type) {
            case .Insert:

                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

            case .Delete:

                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

            case .Update:

                self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

        switch(type) {
        case .Insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

What about `UICollectionViewController`? I haven't found alternative way to implement `controllerWillChangeContent` and `controllerDidChangeContent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collectionView` works somewhat different than `tableView`, you need to use `performBatchUpdates`

```
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController?
var iip = [NSIndexPath]()
var dip = [NSIndexPath]()
var ins: NSIndexSet?
var des: NSIndexSet?

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    if controller == frc {

        switch(type) {
        case .Insert:

            iip.append(newIndexPath)

        case .Delete:

            dip.append(indexPath)

        case .Update:

            self.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch(type) {
    case .Insert:

        ins = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
    case .Delete:


        des = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    self.collectionView!.performBatchUpdates({

        self.collectionView!.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(self.iip)
        self.collectionView!.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(self.dip)
        if self.ins != nil {
            self.collectionView!.insertSections(self.ins!)
        }
        if self.des != nil {
            self.collectionView!.deleteSections(self.des!)
        }

        }, completion: {completed in

            self.iip.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.dip.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.ins = nil
            self.des = nil
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by checking to see if the section of the new index path is greater than the number of sections in the collection view, and then performing batch updates.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath()
// index path of item to be inserted
if indexPath.section > collectionView.numberOfSections - 1 {
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        let set = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)
        collectionView.insertSections(set)
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
    }, completion: nil)
} else {
    collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```